# Laravel 4 testing; 'phpunit' is not recognized?

Tags: php, phpunit, laravel

http://four.laravel.com/docs/testing Says "After installing a new Laravel application, simply run `phpunit` on the command line to run your tests."

`phpunit` isn't recognized, I also tried `php artisian test` and `php artisan phpunit`

Is `phpunit` in some weird folder, or is it actually not included with Laravel? I don't want to install it and have two if it is.

Comment: `phpunit` is a separated application. http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/installation.html

Answer (score 60, accepted):

### Install with composer

An easy way to get up and running with PHPUnit (without needing to install Pear and clutter up every system you want to use this on) is to include it in your composer.json file, like

```
"phpunit/phpunit": "4.0.*",
```

Then after doing a `composer update` you'll be able to run PHPUnit from command line like this:

```
vendor/bin/phpunit
```

Since phpunit will be installed into the vendor/bin folder.

This will install PHPUnit to this project only, not your whole system. So when you want it gone, you simply remove the line from your composer.json file, run composer update, and poof, not a trace.

### Installing for development environments only

If you only want to use this during development, add the composer line inside the "require-dev" section. That way it will only be installed when you opt to install dev dependancies via:

```
php composer.phar install --dev
```

or

```
php composer.phar update
```

Comment: you could use:
require-dev block in composer for development environment too.

Comment: I found this way to update dependencies in a plugin I installed and I've been using it to save time (it adds to composer.json and updates): composer require phpunit/phpunit:3.7.* --dev

Comment: If people still have problems with this, can also use this [post](http://docker.lhsm.com.br/fd54567a-36fe-468f-ae8d-b7181919c1dd) to understand it

Answer (score 4):

If you are a window user and you are having this issue, do this:

You need to tell Window where to find PHPUnit command, you can first of all verify that this file exists in your Laravel project under /vendor/bin

[image]

Finally you need to append the full path to `/vendor/bin` in your window PATH variable,

To do this:
1. Right-click on 'Computer' then click properties

[image]

2. On the second window click `Advanced system settings`

[image]

3. On the next window under `Advanced` click `Environmental Variables`

[image]

4. On the next window double-click `PATH` then set PATH variable by appending

the full path to your `laravel-project/vendor/bin;` Notice the `;` at the end.

NB: Other variables might already exists in the PATH, so ensure you don't overwrite them by appending your own at the very end

5. Finally click `Ok` on all the dialog boxes

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to use phpunit is to put [phpunit.phar](http://pear.phpunit.de/get/phpunit.phar) in the root of your application and to run it with **php phpunit.phar**.

Comment: The link above is old, the current link and instructions are here: https://phpunit.de/getting-started.html

Answer (score -1):

If you run into "phpunit requires ext-dom" it's because php-xml isn't installed.

Answer (score -3):

You need to install phpunit and the best way is with pear.

```
pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de
pear install phpunit/PHPUnit
```

If you don't have pear installed, check [this](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.getting.php) regarding pear installation.

Comment: "the best way"? Please define criterias you've used to estimate it as "the best"

Comment: @zerkms "the best way"="easiest" in this case.

Comment: Pear? Are you kidding? Use composer, see comment above