# guard-laravel reports "phpunit is not installed on your machine"

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, guard

I'm using Jeffrey Way's wonderful [Laravel-Guard](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Laravel-Guard) on a Laravel 4 project I'm building, and for the most part, it seems to be working as intended, except for when I try to get the phpunit part working.

Upon running `guard`, and editing a file, I get this in the console:

```
19:49:53 - ERROR - phpunit is not installed on your machine.
```

I've tried two things to make this work, first I tried [installing phpunit via composer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16138050/laravel-4-testing-phpunit-is-not-recognized), then I tried [installing it via PEAR](http://www.santiagolizardo.com/article/how-to-install-pear-and-phpunit-in-debianubuntu/57001) - neither worked.

I'm running Debian 7.

Can anyone help? Thank you.

Comment: What error did you get when installing via composer? (if any)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What error message do you get?

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16138050/laravel-4-testing-phpunit-is-not-recognized) on installing php-unit via composer. Notice the path to `phpunit`. You may want to alias that to `phpunit` command works anywhere.

Alternatively, you may need/want to install it globally. I've had luck installing it via a package manager. **edit:** You may have already tried this method :/

```
$ sudo apt-get install php-pear # The same on Debian ??
$ sudo pear upgrade PEAR
$ sudo pear config-set auto_discover 1
$ sudo pear install pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit
```

**Note:** May need PEAR dependencies, see here: http://www.giocc.com/installing-phpunit-on-ubuntu-11-04-natty-narwhal.html

Comment: Hi, thank you for this - I'm not sure why, but the instructions you provided in the link seem to have made it work. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about Laravel-Guard specifically, but I found the easiest way to install phpunit without needing to do anything with PEAR was to do a stand-alone composer-based install.

I created a directory `/opt/phpunit` (because I couldn't think of anywhere better to put it), and then created the file `/opt/phpunit/composer.json`:

```
{
    "require": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "3.7.*"
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "/usr/local/bin/"
    }
}
```

You may need to adjust the bin-dir setting to match somewhere on your path. This is critical - otherwise anything looking for phpunit will not be able to find it.

Then you can just run `composer install` - it will download phpunit for you and put a symlink to the launch script in /usr/local/bin,

```
dev1:~$ which phpunit
/usr/local/bin/phpunit
```

Where (on my machine) `/usr/local/bin/phpunit` becomes a symlink to `/opt/phpunit/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/composer/bin/phpunit`

... and it just works. Of course, you will need to manually update occasionally using `composer update` to get the latest phpunit code.

I got these instructions from here: [Chapter 3. Installing PHPUnit](http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/installation.html)